# K6: Dependant Scenarios

Tags: k6

Is it possible to run scenarios in series, with dependancy? I.E Output of one scenario as input to another?

From the [documentation](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/), it seems like scenarios can be made somewhat serial with `startTime`? But not sure about dependent scenarios. Is this possible?

I know that in a single scenario can have multiple APIs that can be serially tested with dependency.

The end goal is to have a summary for each API. In a single scenario, the average is given for the overall test and not each API.